# How to set a foreground color in XAML?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

**In Xamarin.Forms, how can I set the foreground color for a textbox in XAML?**

I tried the following:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Entry}">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
  </Style>
```

I've also tried:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Entry}">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="ForegroundColor" Value="Black" />
  </Style>
```

When I attempt to launch the application, I receive an unexpected exception.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin Forums answered it for me:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Entry}">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
  </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreground and Background property of xaml control object are of type [Brush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/brushes).

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="whiteColorBrush" Color="white" />
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Entry}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource whiteColorBrush}" />
</Style>
```